# Jira notification integration with Skype

Tags: notifications, integration, jira, skype

Is there a way to integrate Jira notifcations into a specific Skype group chat? Say when a specific board gets a new ticket it then sends a notification to a Skype group chat.

Answer (score 3):

Its software! everything is possible.

You could define Web hooks in your instance and call a custom made web page (eg. JSP) and then you could send messages to Skype via Skype API from this code.

Webhooks are explained here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Webhooks

A sample JAVA based Skype API can be found here:
https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api

I know this explanation is very high-level but that would be my approach.

There are a some other possibilities so solve that - eg. a JIRA Plugin, or hack the original code (don't do the last!) - but this depends on your preferences and if you use a Cloud based Jira service or host it by your own.

Best Regards